# Core data fetch request not working

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2

I have `ShopItem` and `Product` tables. `Product` has relation to `ShopItem`. I want to get all products from `ShopItem` object. I have created a method at `ShopItem` class

```
class ShopItem: NSManagedObject {
      func fetchProducts(q: String) {
           // some code ...
          let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")
                fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(
            format: "shopitem == %@ AND keyword == %@",
            self.objectID, String(jsonObj["keyword"])
        )
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
        do {
           fetchResults = try self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Product]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Fetching from the store failed")
        }
      }
    }
```

At logs it generates me the following sql:

```
    SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZPRODUCT_TITLE, t0.ZPRODUCT_URL, 
t0.ZSHOPITEM FROM ZPRODUCT t0 WHERE ( t0.ZSHOPITEM = ? AND  
t0.ZKEYWORD = ?)  LIMIT 1
```

And results is always empty.

Comment: `jsonObj` looks like a global variable. It is not very good design to have a class rely on an external global.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an advice: take a look at [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). It dramatically reduces the amount of code you have to write when working with Core Data, and it takes about 10 minutes to get used to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a relationship, why the fetch request? If everything is set up correctly, you just filter your products by keyword.

```
// filter by kw
let filteredProducts = shopItem.products.filter { $0.keyword == kw }
```

Comment: I haven't acess to products :( Here is my relation at product model:
http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/15/1009/h_1444382236_7511592_66d2e9de55.png

Comment: From your image this is not set up correctly. You need to also set up the reverse relationship. Read up on how Core Data works.

Answer (score 1):

Your fetch request looks correct (although you don't need to pass `self.objectID` in your predicate, `self` is sufficient).  When I see mysteriously empty relationships it's typically one of two things:

1. You aren't setting the relationship at creation like you think you are (or whatever even relates the two entities).
2. You are setting the relationship, but you have a to-one relationship configured in your data model instead of a to-many, which means only the last relationship you create will be present.

Comment: To debug the sort of thing Charles is mentioning, I sometimes find it useful to use the XML backing store instead of the SQLite one. It's simpler (for me anyway) to read the XML than to dig into the SQLite tables.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonObj["keyword"]` returns an optional.
The `String` representation will look like `Optional("keywordValue")`

Unwrap the optional or use optional bindings if the value can be nil.

Comment: > Unwrap the optional or use optional bindings if the value can be nil.


can you explain this ?

Comment: if you know that the dictionary contains always a key `keyword` write `jsonObj["keyword"]!`. About optional bindings please read the appropriate chapter in the Swift Language Guide. If you want to write code in Swift you have to understand the functionality of optionals.